# Why does reducing the font-size of a SPAN element inside a paragraph increase the height of the paragraph?

Tags: html, font-size, css

I am displaying two DIV panels with the code below. The only difference between the two panels is that the SPAN element within the first DIV element has a `font-size: 14px` style applied to it while that of the second DIV element doesn't have this style. On Firefox as well as Chrome the first panel appears to have a greater height than the second one. Here is a demo URL: http://jsfiddle.net/UWX2u/

A copy of the code follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Margin border</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    line-height: 38px;
    font-size: 32px;
}

#panel1 {
    background: #00a000;
    float: left;
}

#panel2 {
    background: orange;
    float: left;
}

#panel1 p span {
    font-size: 14px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="panel1">
        <p>Foo <span>Bar</span></p>
    </div>

    <div id="panel2">
        <p>Foo <span>Bar</span></p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

With Firebug I could see that the computed height of the P element in the first DIV is 44.1833px while that of the P element in the second DIV is 38px. Why does this difference occur?

If I remove the `line-height: 38px` property from the CSS, both DIV elements have the same height. Here is a page that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/FJUDn/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### As to "Why" it Happens

[According to W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) (bold emphasis added),

> 'line-height' specifies the ***minimal*** height of line boxes within the
>   element. The minimum height consists of a **minimum height above** the
>   baseline and a **minimum depth below** it ... The height and depth of the font above 
>   and below the baseline are **assumed to be metrics that are contained in the font**.

So what this tells me is that

1) the `line-height` can go taller if need be (it is just a minimum), and

2) your shrinking of the font would seem to be shifting how the font applies the minimum *above and below* the baseline of the `span` for the `line-height: 38px`. Apparently the smaller font size redistributes more spacing *below* the baseline of the smaller font, pushing the `p` tag taller. This seems confirmed in that if you add to the `span` a `vertical-align: top` [as I did here](http://jsfiddle.net/FJUDn/3/), then the baseline shifts up for the smaller font, and no size change occurs in the `p` tag.

Comment: @Spongman: It answers "why" in the #2 point, as "the smaller font size redistributes more spacing _below_ the baseline ... pushing the `p` tag taller." That is, it the baseline stays at the same point, but puts more below and therefore requires the `p` to expand to accommodate the extra needed.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure as to *why* it is impacting it but if you add the line-height attribute to the span, as I have in this..

http://jsfiddle.net/GQhZR/

..it solves the issue.

The line height therefore, before being corrected with some css, is larger than that of the parent panel.

css edit:

```
#panel1 p span {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px; 
}
```